# CORS not working with Uber API OAuth endpoints

Tags: javascript, oauth, cors, uber-api

I am trying to make client-side JS calls to Uber API endpoints which require the OAuth Bearer token, such as `/v1/me`, but I am receiving an error that the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is not present on the response.

I have successfully obtained a Bearer token (server-side) to use in the Authorization header in the GET request.

In my Uber API application settings, I have my Origin URI set to my development server (https://localhost:9000).

Here is how I call the `/v1/me` endpoint:

```js
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'https://api.uber.com/v1/me');
xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer MY_BEARER_TOKEN");
xhr.send();
```

In Chrome developer console I get the following error:

`No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource`

To ensure that my Bearer token is valid, I **successfully** tested it using curl:

```
curl -H 'Authorization: Bearer MY_BEARER_TOKEN' 'https://api.uber.com/v1/me'
```

On a side note, I am able to **successfully** make calls to the API endpoints which do NOT require OAuth Bearer token, such as `/products` and `/estimates/price` using the Authorization Token header like so:

```js
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'https://api.uber.com/v1/products');
xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Token MY_SERVER_TOKEN");
xhr.send();
```

This leads me to believe that the problem is not an Uber API app configuration setting such as incorrect Origin URI.

One final note, when I obtain the OAuth token I am making the request from a Node Express app running on my development server at https://localhost:8080, which is different from where I am running my client-side JS app at https://localhost:9000. Making the request from the same port did not solve the problem however.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After emailing with Uber tech support, the problem was that CORS was not properly setup on their end. As of yesterday the /v1/me endpoint is now working for me with no changes to my app configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using an iFrame anywhere in your app? That problem usually comes up when I'm requesting to use an iFrame with a product that doesn't normally allow people to do so.